# Common way to compare timestamp in Oracle, PostgreSQL and SQL Server

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, postgresql

I am writing an SQL query which involves finding if timestamp falls in particular range of days.

I have written that in the PostgreSQL but it doesn't works in Oracle and SQL Server:

```
AND creation_date < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '5 days')
AND creation_date >= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '15 days')
```

Is there are common way to compare the timestamp across different databases?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not a SQL Server expert but I know this works on Oracle and Postgres and I suspect it may work on MSSQL but have no way to test it ATM.

```
AND creation_date < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '5' day)
AND creation_date >= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '15' day)
```

Or if you are using the date type instead of timestamp, you could do this but I'm pretty sure it wouldn't work on MSSQL. And the DATE type is quite different between Oracle and Pg.

```
AND creation_date < CURRENT_DATE - 5
AND creation_date >= CURRENT_DATE - 15
```

As was noted in the comments for OMG Ponies, you can only add ints to Date types not timestamps. (Oracle silently casts the timestamp to date)

Comment: You could CAST both fields to a DATE type to fix the problem with integers: CAST(creation_date AS DATE) < CURRENT_DATE - 5

Comment: So I'm testing on SQL Server this morning and I'm amazed to find that it doesn't have an interval type. But it looks like in 2008 they added a date data type so the current_date - 5 may work there. Otherwise you'll have to add an implicit cast for timestamp -> date in Postgres and use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP... assuming that having a single query that will run on all three is really that important.

Answer (score 8):

### How to compare two timestamps in postgresql, the following returns true:

```
select to_timestamp('2010-01-01 10:10:85.123', 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:MI:SS.MS') <
    to_timestamp('2012-01-01 10:10:85.123', 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:MI:SS.MS');
```

Returns true because the `2012` is after the `2010`

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is common syntax that'll work across all database engines. In SQL Server, you do it like this:

```
AND creation_date BETWEEN DateAdd(dd, -5, GetUtcDate()) AND DateAdd(dd, -15, GetUtcDate())
```

I'm not sure about Oracle...

Answer (score 2):

**Oracle** (I have tested both of these solutions):

```
AND (creation_date BETWEEN sysdate-15 AND sysdate-6)
```

This syntax is also valid:

```
AND (creation_date BETWEEN current_timestamp - INTERVAL '15' DAY 
                       AND current_timestamp - INTERVAL '6' DAY)
```

Note that SYSDATE and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP are synonymous (sort of - see comments).

Note that BETWEEN returns values **inclusive** of the bounds. Since you are looking for values which are **`>=`** date-15 but **`<`** date-5, you need to specify -15 to -6 when using BETWEEN. **The answers using an upper bound of -5 with a BETWEEN expression are wrong.**

Comment: It's backwards, and the intended upper limit value is incorrect.

Comment: @Ponies: Thanks; that was sloppy of me. Fixed.

Comment: Not a big deal but in Oracle SYSDATE and CURRENT_DATE are synonymous and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is similar but of type TIMESTAMP instead of DATE.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from timing where (db_time < CURRENT_DATE) AND (db_time > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' DAY)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Again this is specific for Oracle, assume intime is TIMESTAMP(3) data type, you can do this

```
select * from MYTABLE where intime >= to_timestamp('2014-10-01 7:00:56', 'YYYY-MM-dd HH24:MI:SS')
```