# comparing time and date and displaying its status in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

So I have this piece of code to populate the results of my bidding listing in a table:

```
$query = "SELECT item, start_time, start_date, description, price FROM items"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
         echo"<tr><td>$row[item]    </td>";
         echo" <td>  $row[price]</td>";
         echo" <td>  $row[description]</td>";   
         echo"<td> $row[start_time]</td>";  
         echo"<td> $row[start_date]</td>";  
                                                      }
```

However, I would like to add another column 'STATUS' which will display the status of the bidding either active or inactive based on the comparison of the user defined 'start_time' and 'start_date' value with todays time and date. How am I to do so? THe current data type for 'start_time' and 'start_date' in MySQL is time and date. Thanks.

Comment: splitting time and date in to two fields in a db is a bad idea, you lose all the functionality of the date-time functions.

Comment: shouldn't it be end date/time? Not start date/time.

Comment: Okay, I will merge the two fields into one timestamp data column. Thanks.

Comment: David, I'm trying to create a real-time bidding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your DB column is set up as timestamp, you can do it two ways.  I definitely agree with the comment that you should be using timestamp in your database.  It is less data intense than saving your UNIX timestamp as an integer and its not hard to get your date out of sql.

1) In your sql SELECT, you can add something like:

```
DATE_FORMAT( `scheduled_release`, \'%m-%d-%Y\') AS formattedDate

Select `name`, DATE_FORMAT( `scheduled_release`, \'%m-%d-%Y\') AS formattedDate WHERE id = ?
```

2) `date("m/j/y", strtotime( $row[date ) );`

Comment: I can display the timestamp properly but how do I compare between the two timestamps? Is it possible to compare them in the SQL statement?

Comment: you can just use operators on the columns like any other time: WHERE `dateColumn` > `secondDateColumn`  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505382/common-way-to-compare-timestamp-in-oracle-postgres-and-sql-server)[/link] It is a little more complicated, but it should show you.